# Writing middleware for event handlers

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

**Use case:**

I have to handle several events which require an "available client". So in each event handler I first have to try to get an available client. If there is no client available I'll respond with a "Service unavailable" message. Right now I've implemented that requirement like this:

```
public constructor(consumer: RpcConsumer) {
  consumer.on('requestA', this.onRequestA);
}

private onRequestA = async (msg: RpcConsumerMessage) {
    const client: RequestClient = this.getClient(msg);
    if (client == null) {
      return;
    }

   msg.reply(await client.getResponseA());
}

private getClient(msg: RpcConsumerMessage): RequestClient {
    const client: RequestClient= this.clientManager.getClient();
    if (client == null) {
      const err: Error = new Error('Currently there is no client available to process this request');
      msg.reply(undefined, MessageStatus.ServiceUnavailable, err);

      return;
    }

    return client;
}
```

**The problem:**

I don't want to check for an available client in all event handlers again and again. Instead I thought a middleware would perfectly fit into this use case. It would check for an available client and passes on the client instance if there is one. If there is not available client it will respond with the error message.

**The question:**

How would I write such a middleware for this case?

Comment: If this is TypeScript, please mark it as such.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides I'll add the typescript badge sorry. Even though I use TypeScript it's a JavaScript problem. That's why I originally ommitted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a curried method for this:

```
 private withClient(cb: (client: RequestClient) => string | Promise<string>) {
  return function(msg: RpcConsumerMessage) {
    const client: RequestClient= this.clientManager.getClient();
    if (client == null) {
      const err: Error = new Error('Currently there is no client available to process this request');
      msg.reply(undefined, MessageStatus.ServiceUnavailable, err);

      return;
    }

    msq.reply(await cb(client));
   };
 }
```

So you can use it as:

```
 private onRequestA = withClient(client => client.getResponseA());
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly I don't think you actually NEED middleware, although you might choose to go that route.

You can just have a module that is in charge of finding a client and serving one up if it is available. This would look something like this:

```
const _client;

module.exports = {
    getClient
}

getClient(){
     return _client;
}

function setClient(){
    //Your logic to find an available client
    //run this whenever a client disconnects (if there is an event for that) or until you are connected to a client
    _clent = client; //When you find that client set it to `_client`. You will return this everytime someone calls getClient.
}
```

The advantage here is that once you find a client, the module will serve up that same client until you are disconnected from it. The trick then is just making sure that you are always trying to connect to client when you are disconnected - even when there are no requests. I hope this makes sense.